# Setting DateTime display format at runtime with MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, datetime

I'm rendering an input control which holds a DateTime value:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime? ScheduledDateTime { get; set; }
```

The formatting applied to the input is stored as a user preference which is retrieved from the database at runtime.

So, I've got the following value at run-time:

> YYYY-MM-DD

The actual formatting not-withstanding, how can I tell my model binder to format the DateTime as specified? All examples I've found rely on setting the DateFormatString attribute, but this is only able to be set with a compile time constant. This makes it unusable for my purposes.

Something with override the default model binder? Anyone got an example, I haven't been able to turn one up Googling.

EDIT: Maybe I create a new HtmlHelper which will handle the conversion at runtime?

EDIT2: Pretty sure I'm going to go about it like this. Pardon the overly verbose naming convention:

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ScheduledDateTime, string.Format("{0:" + User.GetDateFormatStringAsCSharpFormat(SessionManager.Default.User.DateFormat)+ "}", Model.ScheduledDateTime))%>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This uses Razor syntax but same principle applies

```
@{
  var dateFormat = (DateTime)Viewbag.PreferredDateFormatForUser //Just grab it from where ever you have it
}


@Html.TextBox("ScheduleDateTime", model.ScheduleDateTime.ToString(dateFormat))
```

Here is the reference for custom date time format strings

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Comment: Yep. This is what I'm doing just in other syntax. :)